# Creating a list that is sequence of actions taken by user

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a few lines of code that create a chronological list of all the utm sources associated with a given anonymous_id. In the instance there there is only 1 utm source associated with the anon id, I would like to store all of this in a list under a column.

I then convert these 'states' into a list and create a new dataframe showing the sequence of states and the number of anonymous id's that went through the same sequence of states.

The problem is that when I create a lambda function to create the list of sequences, I exclude instances where the anonymous id only had 1 utm source.

This is the code I have written:

```
grouped = (file
           .sort_values(by='ts')
           .groupby('anonymous_id').utm_source
           .agg(list)
           .reset_index()
          )
grouped['transitions'] = grouped.utm_source.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x,x[1:])))
all_transitions = Counter(chain(*grouped.transitions.tolist()))
transitions = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(all_transitions,orient='index').reset_index()
```

Here is a sample of what the grouped dataframe looks like

Here is a sample of my data:

```
anonymous_id                               utm_source   transitions
0   00003df1-be12-47b8-b3b8-d01c84a22fdf    [nan, nan]  [(nan, nan)]
1   00009cc0-279f-4ccf-aea4-f6af1f2bb75a    [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]   [(nan, nan), (nan, nan), (nan, nan), (nan, nan...
2   0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78    [nan, nan, nan] [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)]
3   0000c906-7060-4521-8090-9cd600b08974    [gumtree]   []
4   0000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462    [facebook]  []
5   0000df7e-2579-4071-8aa5-814ab294bf9a    [nan, nan, nan] [(nan, nan), (nan, nan)]
6   0000f8ea-3aa6-4423-9247-1d9580d378e1    [facebook]  []
```

So for example where the user only went through gumtree, transitions shows a blank because there is only one utm_source associated with the user

File (dataframe converted to a dictionary for your convenience):

```
{'anonymous_id': {0: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  1: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  2: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  3: '0000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462',
  4: '0002269a-1e39-4cdf-a43e-cecf0a277c1c',
  5: '00044853-26bc-4c38-93a7-cad6860640ac',
  6: '00074e2d-f7aa-4fd1-baaa-06e56961d15a',
  7: '000efd5a-8ec6-4a3a-904d-7376b651da26',
  8: '000f3947-1255-457f-b9bf-81cea6a62075',
  9: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  10: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  11: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  12: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  13: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  14: '000f66e9-4784-4ed7-b041-7b532c5276a6',
  15: '00031151-9521-4895-a593-eb06033ea6f7',
  16: '00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a',
  17: '00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a',
  18: '00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a',
  19: '00050977-de0e-464d-b3e7-448b6b20268a'},
 'ts': {0: '2019-06-18 09:11:14.409000',
  1: '2019-06-18 09:11:15.028000',
  2: '2019-06-18 09:12:03.118000',
  3: '2018-05-17 20:31:32.203000',
  4: '2019-02-24 16:08:32.661000',
  5: '2018-10-03 18:50:11.353000',
  6: '2018-07-21 04:55:27.496000',
  7: '2018-11-28 13:25:36.289000',
  8: '2019-04-11 18:52:50.449000',
  9: '2019-05-31 08:23:04.640000',
  10: '2019-06-03 15:39:23.523000',
  11: '2019-06-03 15:39:48.189000',
  12: '2019-06-04 05:06:51.927000',
  13: '2019-06-05 04:41:42.928000',
  14: '2019-06-05 16:22:26.982000',
  15: '2019-03-27 16:00:56.908000',
  16: '2018-09-02 04:58:38.524000',
  17: '2018-09-02 04:58:38.622000',
  18: '2018-09-02 04:59:38.497000',
  19: '2018-09-02 04:59:42.944000'},
 'utm_source': {0: nan,
  1: nan,
  2: nan,
  3: 'facebook',
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: 'email',
  7: nan,
  8: 'facebook',
  9: nan,
  10: nan,
  11: nan,
  12: nan,
  13: nan,
  14: nan,
  15: nan,
  16: nan,
  17: nan,
  18: nan,
  19: nan}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by adding a conditional statement to my lambda function to test if the length of the list was greater than 1. If the length of the list is greater than one then return the sequence of items found in the list, else return the only value in the list:

```
grouped['transitions'] = grouped.utm_source.apply(lambda x: list(zip(x,x[1:])) if len(x) > 1 else list(x))
```